# How to count joined errors in Go 1.20?

Tags: go, error-handling

As far I understand, `errors.Join()` is a out-of-the-box replacement for multi-error collection types like hashicorp/multierror that collects errors that occur side-by-side. This question does not address regular error wrapping/unwrapping.

While I am replacing production code, some tests fail while trying to count the joined errors. Both number and type of error is important to manage the business case. This worked with hashicorp/multierror because a certain string will be generated, something like `3 errors occurred`.

```golang
package main

import "errors"

func doSomething() error {
    var multierror error
    err1 := errors.New("Hello")
    multierror = errors.Join(err1, err1)
    err2 := errors.New("World")
    multierror = errors.Join(err2, err1)

    return multierror
}

// somewhere else
func test_doSomething(t *testing.T) {
   actual := doSomething()
   assert.Len(t, 2, len(actual)????) // help
}
```

How can I count the number of errors once I used `errors.Join()`?

I cannot find a method to inspect the nature of the error slice inside the joined error, and inspecting said error slice itself is impossible because it is private.

Using `errors.Unwrap(err)` might be a way though all I get is either an error or `nil` if it is the last one. It does not exactly let's one address errors for counting besides `errors.As/.Is`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`errors.Join()`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Join) documents that:

> A non-nil error returned by Join implements the Unwrap() []error method.

So the `error` returned by `errors.Join()` will have an `Unwrap() []error` method. [Type assert](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) an interface type holding that method, and you can call it, it will return the joined errors as a slice:

For example:

```
err1 := errors.New("err1")
err2 := errors.New("err2")
err := errors.Join(err1, err2)

if uw, ok := err.(interface{ Unwrap() []error }); ok {
    errs := uw.Unwrap()
    fmt.Println("Number of joined errors:", len(errs))
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/IX29__IDjtF)):

```
Number of joined errors: 2
```

Comment: Ah I must've missed the return type of said `Unwrap()`. That works like a charm. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @PhilippPixel There are 2 "kinds" of `Unwrap()` methods. There's one we used here that returns a slice when multiple errors are joined, and there's another that returns a single `error` if you wrap a single `error` with e.g. using `fmt.Errorf("cause: %w", err)`.